# Removing commas from CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, export

I created an Excel .XLSX file, reformatted the columns from currency to numbers with 2 decimals and no thousands separator, then exported to a .CSV file, then to a .TXT file.

Once I did that, the number columns in just one column ended up with commas (1000 separator).  How do I stop this from happening?  With the programming I have to upload a file I can have no commas within my numbers.

Comment: Ensure the column is formatted as a number in Excel and not "General" for "Text". Also, a CSV _IS_ a text file, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you converted it from CSV to TXT?

Comment: A sample row or two from the file would help

Answer (score 3):

If the CSV file uses tab characters, or some other delimiter between fields other than a comma, this is easy:

Download the free, open source GNUWin version of [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) and put it in C:\Windows\SYSTEM32

Them enter this command

```
sed "s/,//" OLDFILE.CSV > NEWFILE.TXT
```

If your CSV uses commas to separate the fields, well, use Excel to output a new version which uses tabs instead of commas to separate the fields before regenerating a new version of OLDFILE.CSV.

Answer (score 2):

I can't duplicate your error, so I am leaning towards OS setting, or application misconfiguration. If you pre-format your column to not `Use 1000 Separator` and you save as CSV or TXT (tab delimited) file, the values will not show up with commas within the data cell.

The only exception I can think of is if your decimal place for your country is a comma and not period. USA the default decimal place is a period. It may not be a decimal in other countries.

In Excel 2013,

- Select your column (e.g. left click on A, B, or C)
- Right-click on column and select Format Columns
- Under Number tab, uncheck `Use 1000 Separator (,)`

[image]